# For $A=U\Sigma V^{T}$ and $B=U\Sigma^{\delta}V^{T}$ we get $\|A-B\|_{F}^{2}=\delta^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

While studying for my final in numerical linear algebra, I came across with the following statement:

> Let $A$ be a matrix with SVD decomposition so $A=U\Sigma V^{T}$ with singular values $\sigma_{1}\geq\sigma_{2}\geq\ldots\geq\sigma_{r}>0$. If we will add $\delta$ to some $\sigma_{kk}$ in the diagonal of $\Sigma$ then for the matrix $B=U\Sigma^{\delta}V^{T}$ we get $\|A-B\|_{F}^{2}=\delta^{2}$.

I'm trying to prove this statement for myself, but I can't seem to figure it out. How should I prove it?

**Edit**: The following proof is valid?

$$
\|A-B\|_{F}^{2}=\|U\Sigma V^{T}-U\Sigma^{\delta}V^{T}\|_{F}^{2}=\|U\left(\Sigma-\Sigma^{\delta}\right)V^{T}\|_{F}^{2}=\|UXV^{T}\|_{F}^{2}$$
where $X$ is the matrix that has $-\delta$ in $k,k$ and $0$ otherwise. So we get:
$$
\|A-B\|_{F}^{2}=\|UXV^{T}\|_{F}^{2}=\|X\|_{F}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{ij}^{2}=\left(-\delta\right)^{2}=\delta^{2}
$$
Will it be valid without the need of $\sigma_{1}\geq\sigma_{2}\geq\ldots\geq\sigma_{r}>0$?

Comment: Your proof is correct. And it would still be valid without the condition that you mention.